# Particular targets of high angular resolution infrared telescopes

Tags: astronomy, telescopes, observational-astronomy, instrument, infrared-radiation

I work in the field of infrared [interferometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_interferometer), specifically instrumentation.

As such, I need to be aware of the science goals of such an instrument. Is there a quick list of important and contemporary targets that such an instrument of high angular resolution would be pointed at?

(By "high", I mean objects that subtend a small angle on the sky.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious targets are protostar disks (T Tauri, [Serpens FIRS 1](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2715)), the Milky Way's central black hole Sgr A*, and nearby large stars (Betelgeuse).

The [MPIfR interferometry group web page](http://www.mpifr.de/div/ir-interferometry/) has an impressive sample

Answer (score 1):

*[Searching Google Scolar for "Particular Targets of High Angular Resolution Infrared Telescopes"](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?q=Particular+Targets+of+High+Angular+Resolution+Infrared+Telescopes.&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart)*
gives good citations.